# How to add an outline to an image in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's one of the images I want to apply the outline on, and how it's supposed to look:

[image]

[image: image with outline]

And here's the code that's the closest to what I want (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62931912/16775029)):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import math
img = Image.open(f"frames/frame000028.png")

def stroke(origin_image, threshold, stroke_size, colors):
    img = np.array(origin_image)
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    padding = stroke_size + 50
    alpha = img[:,:,2]
    rgb_img = img[:,:,0:3]
    bigger_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(rgb_img, padding, padding, padding, padding, 
                                        cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0, 0, 0, 0))
    alpha = cv2.copyMakeBorder(alpha, padding, padding, padding, padding, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)
    bigger_img = cv2.merge((bigger_img, alpha))
    h, w, _ = bigger_img.shape
    
    _, alpha_without_shadow = cv2.threshold(alpha, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # threshold=0 in photoshop
    alpha_without_shadow = 255 - alpha_without_shadow
    dist = cv2.distanceTransform(alpha_without_shadow, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_3)  # dist l1 : L1 , dist l2 : l2
    stroked = change_matrix(dist, stroke_size)
    stroke_alpha = (stroked * 255).astype(np.uint8)

    stroke_b = np.full((h, w), colors[0][2], np.uint8)
    stroke_g = np.full((h, w), colors[0][1], np.uint8)
    stroke_r = np.full((h, w), colors[0][0], np.uint8)

    stroke = cv2.merge((stroke_b, stroke_g, stroke_r, stroke_alpha))
    stroke = cv2pil(stroke)
    bigger_img = cv2pil(bigger_img)
    result = Image.alpha_composite(stroke, bigger_img)
    return result

def change_matrix(input_mat, stroke_size):
    stroke_size = stroke_size - 1
    mat = np.ones(input_mat.shape)
    check_size = stroke_size + 1.0
    mat[input_mat > check_size] = 0
    border = (input_mat > stroke_size) & (input_mat <= check_size)
    mat[border] = 1.0 - (input_mat[border] - stroke_size)
    return mat

def cv2pil(cv_img):
    cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)
    pil_img = Image.fromarray(cv_img.astype("uint8"))
    return pil_img
    
    
output = stroke(img, threshold=0, stroke_size=10, colors=((42,102,209),))
output.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post your own attempt to solve the problem, so we can help you with potential issues you are having.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The outline is supposed to be on the top only, but it's spread across the sides and bottom.