# how to add border to an irregular shaped image using python

Tags: python, image, border, cloudinary, wand

i want to add borders to an image which have an irregular shape. i want to dynamically add border for different shaped images during runtime using python just like cloudinary.
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/unicorn_rainbow.png
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/e_outline,co_red/e_outline,co_rgb:FF7F00/e_outline,co_yellow/e_outline,co_rgb:00FF00/e_outline,co_blue/e_outline,co_rgb:4B0082/e_outline,co_rgb:9400D3/e_outline,co_red/e_outline,co_rgb:FF7F00/e_outline,co_yellow/e_outline,co_rgb:00FF00/e_outline,co_blue/e_outline,co_rgb:4B0082/e_outline,co_rgb:9400D3/unicorn_rainbow.png
like this.
cloudinary is adding different colour borders to a unicorn image.
is this possible using python.
i am currently using wand library but i am open to use any other library if that solves the problem

what i currently have is rectangle border and i am cropping the image to make that a circle using wand

Comment: You can get rid of all the inner details of the unicorn and reduce your image to a simple, solid black unicorn on a white background. Then you can use morphological operations to erode the white (or dilate the black) and fill the new area with a new border of the colour you want. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry i dont have much experience with images. can you tell me which library i should use.currently i am using wand library and i dont know if all this is even possible with wand

Comment: You can use `wand` or **OpenCV** or `scikit-image` - ultimately they all make image files into Numpy arrays, then provide processing functions that work on Numpy arrays. Look at the section that makes all non-red pixels black in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019059/2836621 Then try on your image to make all non-white pixels (i.e. the unicorn) black. Then try some morphology to *"paint"* an outline, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61442120/2836621